# Error Cannot read property 'then' of undefined en md-autocomplete de Angular-material

Tags: angularjs, array

Buenas tardes. Quiero utilizar ***md-autocoplete*** de angular-material pero me lanza el siguiente error:

> angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>   at fetchResults (angular-material.js:23331)
>   at handleQuery (angular-material.js:23437)
>       at MdAutocompleteCtrl.focus (angular-material.js:23022)
>       at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14817), :4:415)
>       at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:15906)
>       at callback (angular.js:25885)
>       at ChildScope.$eval (angular.js:17682)
>       at ChildScope.$apply (angular.js:17782)
>       at HTMLInputElement. (angular.js:25890)
>       at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5110)

el código del autocomplete es este:

`<md-autocomplete md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in getMatches(searchText)" md-item-text="tickets.rut">
  <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{tickets.rut}}</span>
</md-autocomplete>`

y el de mi controlador es este:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/Paneldetencion/app/php/consulta.php',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
})

  .then(function(data) {
     var dat = data.data;
     $scope.tickets= [];
     for (var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) {
      var ticket = {numero : dat[i].numero,
                    rut : dat[i].rut,
                    servicio_id : dat[i].servicio_id};

     $scope.tickets.push(ticket);
  }
  });
```

Aquí al hacer un `console.log($scope.tickets);` los datos los muestra así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: quien ayuda aquí?

Comment: Donde está la implementacion de la función `getMatches` en tu controlador?

Comment: lo solucione, hace un momento... ahora modificare este post.

Comment: En lugar de modificar el post publicalo como auto respuesta ya que es una solución a tu problema :)